# Drawing- Android Programming

Tags: android

I want to draw a straight line following my finger on touch on a canvas, such that ACTION_DOWN point is starting point and ACTION_UP is end point. The path followed by finger can be anything but ultimately the figure should be a line from starting point to end point. Please help me with the onDraw() function.

Comment: keep your code once...

Comment: take a look at Android Examples, there's one "FingerPaint", in your SDK directory, that deals with your requirements

Answer (score 0):

This code draw line when you touch finger from one point to another
this is
DrawLineView.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawLineView extends View {

private Paint paint = new Paint();
private Path path= new Path();
float eventx;
float eventy;

public DrawLineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    eventx=event.getX();
    eventy=event.getY();


    switch(event.getAction()){
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN :
        path.moveTo(eventx, eventy);

        return true;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP :
        path.lineTo(eventx, eventy);

        break;
        default :
             return false;

    }
    invalidate();

    return true;
}

}
```

Activity to start it:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class DrawActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new DrawLineView(this, null));
}


}
```

Comment: Thank You. But with this code I cannot see the line until I lift the finger from screen. It'll be good if the line can be seen following the finger.